# Forall inserts with dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a set of insert commands stored in a table type variable (varchar2). The records are inserted into same columns of the same table.

How can I write forall loop to execute these insert queries?

Thanks

Comment: You have a string of SQL commands you want to execute?

Comment: Yes,Array of strings containing insert commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on nested tables as in the following example (from [PL/SQL Collections and Records - Nested Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99981))

```
FOR i IN names.FIRST .. names.LAST LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(names(i));
END LOOP;
```

and you can run a dynamically created query by means of the [execute immediate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) construct.

Saying that, your problem can be resolved with the following example code.

```
declare
    type table_varchar is table of varchar2(4000);
    tv_inserts table_varchar := table_varchar();
begin
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := 'insert into test_table(col1, col2) values(1, 10)';
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := 'insert into test_table(col1, col2) values(2, 20)';
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := 'insert into test_table(col1, col2) values(3, 30)';

    for ind in tv_inserts.first..tv_inserts.last
    loop
        execute immediate tv_inserts(ind);
    end loop;
end;
```

The [forall statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm) can be used with the execute immediate but [fixing the table name in the string](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531830000346274113) as in the example below

```
declare
    type table_varchar is table of varchar2(4000);
    tv_inserts table_varchar := table_varchar();
begin
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := '1';
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := '2';
    tv_inserts.extend();
    tv_inserts(tv_inserts.count) := '3';

    for ind in tv_inserts.first..tv_inserts.last
    loop
        execute immediate 'insert into test_table(col1) values(:a)'
            using tv_inserts(ind);
    end loop;
end;
```

Note that this approach is not feasible without a previous processing of your input array.

Comment: In my current code i am doing exactly what you have written. Performance is the issue here i need to use forall to insert everything at once, is this possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer with your clarifications.
I suggest you to edit your question adding a snippet of the code that you tried and explaining the performance problem that you are experiencing, otherwise this question will be probably deleted.

Comment: FORALL is certainly the way to go. It doesn't mean that you "insert everything at once". It means that N insert statements will be passed to the SQL engine for processing with a single context switch.

If you can find a way to do all this with a SQL INSERT statement, such as INSERT-SELECT, and not FORALL, it is likely to run even faster.

But be sure to think through error handling on this as well. Is it all or nothing? If 1000 rows are inserted and then the 1001st causes an error, do you want to preserve the first 1000? In this case include SAVE EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: My blog post might help here: http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2014/11/foralls-and-commits.html

Comment: Thanks, but the values are stored in the string format. separated by commas, I guess i have to split each value to an array and then try forall.